# How to implement min left/right in css

Tags: html, css

I have an element in my css which look like below

```
.xyz{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    }
```

Now as expected when I reduce the width of browser window, this element moves towards left. However I want it to stop at a certain point since otherwise it starts overlapping other elements. In principle, this is very similar to min-height and and min-width properties. But there is no such property like min-left or min-top. How can I implement this.

Comment: Please provide a demo in Fiddle

Comment: Have you tried media queries?

Comment: Agree with @Boldewyn media queries are definitely the way to go. likelihood is with about 5 lines it can be done.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I don't know about media queries. I am new to web development. I will check it out.

Comment: @john the element doesn't moves left.It always in the middle when u reduce the width http://jsfiddle.net/6urf2/

Comment: @venkatesh, yes, relative to the browser window, it stays in the center. But if you look at overall screen, it is moving left because the window itself is shrinking.

Comment: @John about media queries: here's a short intro over at MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: I solved it by assigning a min-width to the parent element. It seemed the simplest method. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can estimate the window size, where the movement should stop, (let's say `700px`) you can use media queries:

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .xyz {
    left: 10px;
  }
}
```

Then for windows narrower than `700px`, the element is placed fixed at `left: 10px` (adapt CSS as suited for you).